# Can't std::ostream output a const char array?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

For the fun and experience of it, I'm <del>modifying and</del> exploring the source code for [Blobby Volley 2 1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blobby/files/Blobby%20Volley%202%20%28Linux%29/1.0/blobby2-linux-1.0.tar.gz/download) (Linux).

Well... I **would** be modifying the source code, but I can't even get the program to compile. (Sad, isn't it?)

Here's the code that causes the error:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const ServerInfo& val) {
    return stream << val.name << " (" << val.hostname << ":" << val.port << ")";
    }
```

Trying to compile this with *g++ 5.4.0* gives the following (simplified output--the original output is ~443 lines) error message:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka
>   std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘const char [32]’)
>
> return stream << val.name << " (" << val.hostname << ":" << val.port << ")";

I simplified the code to this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const ServerInfo& val) {
    stream << "hello"; //can't get simpler than this, right?
    return stream;
    }
```

and got

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘const char [6]’)
>
> stream << "hello";

The code that calls it looks like this:

```
std::cout << "duplicate server entry\n";
std::cout << info << "\n"; //it's called here
```

---

The thing I find most surprising is that we all know that `std::cout` and its ilk can handle `char` arrays.

For instance,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    const char a[6] = "hello";
    std::cout << a << std::endl; //No problem here!
    return 0;
    }
```

works without a hitch.

---

Oh, one more thing.

If I include `<string>`, this works:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const ServerInfo& val) {
    stream << std::string("hello");
    return stream;
    }
```

---

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

---

**PS:** Here's a [pastebin of the errors.](http://pastebin.com/UYPHqspD)

**PPS:** Here's the headers that were requested:

```
/* header include */
#include "NetworkMessage.h"

/* includes */
#include <cstring>

#include "UserConfig.h"
#include "SpeedController.h"
```

***PPS:*** If you are wondering why I didn't get an error about `std::ostream` not being defined, check the 3rd paragraph of Sam's answer.

Comment: Can you post, in addition to what you have here, the full error log? There might be something else in there that's important.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Are you *positive* you want it all?

Comment: You're reporting an error that shouldn't normally be happening, so I suspect something else might be up as well. So... yes! :-)

Comment: The most likely answer is that the translation unit in question is missing an include of <iostream>.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I'm getting you your error log. I have to format it first so that you can actually read it though... :D

Comment: @JefréN.: Post *the headers* as well  which you have included in the file which contains this code.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Posted pastebin.

Comment: Sure looks like the errors you get if you didn't `#include <iostream>` - the only overload it knows about is the custom one you wrote.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I'll try it, although I don't think it is theoretically necessary.

Comment: @templatetypedef: That was the problem ... Stunned. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it, if you want.

Comment: Give credit to @SamVarshavchik - he was the first to figure that out. :-)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Congratulations! You're hypothesis proved correct. Do you care to give it as an answer? (Since `iostream` was included in 'main.cpp', I'm still not sure why it was necessary, though.)

Comment: @templatetypedef and everyone else: Thanks for the help and brainstorming. I guess I just learned another lesson in never assuming. :DD

Comment: Every C++ file is compiled independently of all others, so just because you included a header in one file doesn't mean you've included it everywhere.

Comment: Anyone think I should delete this question?

Comment: @templatetypedef: In truth, I include every header I need in each file. However, I didn't think it was *strictly* necessary. Guess it is. Thanks again for the help and explanation. :D

Comment: @JefréN. Deleting the question now would probably save reviewers' work in the long run, since I suspect that's the ultimate fate of this question anyways. But it's up to you. Glad you figured it out though.

Comment: @JasonC: If not for the fact that Sam Varshavchik, the guy who initially guessed what the problem was, gave an answer like I asked him to, I would delete the question. But as it is, I think I'm gonna let stackoverflow take its course ... :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fact that `#include <iostream>` was likely missing was deduced using the Sherlock Holmes approach to debugging: "when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth".

Clearly. `std::ostream` should've have had no problems accepting a `const char *` overload.

Therefore, an overload resolution complaint must mean that `<iostream>` wasn't included. Most C++ library classes are forward-declared all over the place. Including some random header file is likely to get you a forward declaration of `std::ostream`, as a free bonus. So the compiler will not complain about this class not being defined.

But unless `<iostream>` is included, the compiler will not know about all the overloads that are defined there. That's it.

Comment: `#include <ostream>` (which declares the `const char*` overload - 27.7.3.1) would suffice instead of `iostream` (which includes `ostream` - 27.4.1).