# C++ custom Object << for stream

Tags: c++, rest

I'm coding a restclient using the cpprestsdk, currently I have problems with serializing a custom object using <<.
My method:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, User &u){
    return strm << "User{ id=" << u.getId() << ", pw=" << u.getPw() <<
                ", username='" << u.getUsername() + '\''<<
                ", name='" << u.getName() << '\'' <<
                ", firstName='" << u.getFirstName() + '\'' <<
                ", email='" << u.getEmail() + '\'' <<
                ", tel='" << u.getTel() << '\'' <<
                ", local=" << u.getLocal()<<
                ", birthday=" << u.getBirthday() <<
                ", profilePicture=" << (byteToString(u.getProfilePicture())) <<'}';
}



char User::byteToString(std::byte *b) {
    int n = sizeof(b);
    char chars;
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void *>(chars), b, n);// memcpy(chars, b, n);
    return reinterpret_cast<char>(chars);
}
```

In this context, there is also a problem with the byteToString I cab't solve.
The Error:

```
Error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘const char [10]’)
   96 |     return strm << "User{ id=" << u.getId() << ", pw=" << u.getPw() <<
      |            ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            |       |
      |            |       const char [10]
      |            std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

Comment: compiletime erros, edited it

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39217987/580083. Some headers might be missing. You should provide a complete minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I missed a header, thanks @Daniel Langr